# hazelcast deployment implementation

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have an application with a few model classes.  These model classes are stored in Hazelcast maps in my application.  I am trying to use a hazelcast client to connect to the hazelcast server node.  I have map-store-enabled to true and initial load mode set to EAGER.  Should I do the following:

1. Copy the same hazelcast.conf file on both client and server or should I only keep the map store enabled as true on the server (or just the client)?
2. If I keep the map-store-enabled=true on server, I am guessing I need to deploy my map store classes there.  Is that the correct approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client has a different configuration, so there is no point in copying it to the client. Only the server needs to have it.

The mapstore classes need to be on the server since it is only running on the server. The classes of the objects you put in the map need to be available on both client and server.

Comment: just to get it right. if I have a web enabled app, and it uses the client to connect to the server, the web enabled app should not have the map entries in its config & these are maps the web enabled app uses (but the server should have the map entries in its config and also the map store implementation should reside on the server).  I am guessing the map store implementation should only be enabled on one server (not all servers).  Is this correct?

Comment: >> just to get it right ... and also the map store implementation should reside on the server). 

Correct. BTW the client doesn't care if there is server related functionality available, it isn't going to do something unexpected. It is just less clean.


>> I am guessing the map store implementation should only be enabled on one server (not all servers). Is this correct?

The server stuff needs to be on all servers. We do not support distributed classloading, so classes/config needs to be available on all server nodes.

Comment: thank you for responding.  Let's say I have three maps (map1-3 with mapstore implemented), and I have 5 servers (on which I have hazelcast server implemented), should I have map store enabled to true for map1 on all 5 servers?  I can see that for load and store but I am not sure if that will cause issues for loadAll) - should that be on all servers or just one?

Comment: any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310915/load-all-implementation-for-hazelcast

Comment: Is it somehow possible to avoid having the object classes that I put in the map on both sides (i.e. server and client)? For example is there a generic serialization magic that I could apply on the server somehow? Or could I provide the object in JSON or text form to avoid that? I would like to increase separation.

Comment: Currently we don't have something like this; it is in the radar, but don't expect it anytime soon. Storing it it text/json would avoid that.