# load all implementation for hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to use hazelcast server over multiple nodes.  I have implemented the load all in the map store implementation.  I am wondering whether this should only be enabled on on server node or all of them?  If I deploy the same on all nodes, would this not create database read operations which should not be needed.  If I need to deploy the load all only on one node, what is the best strategy (code/API call based or config) that would allow me to cleanly implement the scenario whereby only one server node implements the load all implementation for map store.  I can always deploy different code on different servers but I would like to avoid that and wondering about better choices.

Comment: any thoughts by anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every node needs to have the same configuration/jars etc.

Currently the MapLoader.loadAllKeys is executed on one of the nodes in the cluster. Once the keys are loaded, they are assigned to the owning partitions where the actual data is loaded using the MapLoader.loadAll(keys) method.

Do you think sharing the same configuration/jars is a problem?

Comment: I guess I wanted to be clear on this.  Will hazelcast take responsibility for ensuring that only node calls loadlAll/loadAllkeys or is that something I need to implement?  If the code/config is the same, that would be great (without having to implement logic for making sure that only node calls loadAll)

Comment: You don't need to implement it; it is part of the Hazelcast infrastructure.

Comment: Probably in Hazelcast 3.4 we are going to enrich the loading model. I believe there will be more control on loading all keys per partition, because currently 1 machine is going to be 'victim' to load all keys, but in some cases it is better to spread the load.

Comment: thank you for commenting - what I take from this is the following:  that I should simply deploy my map store implementations (with load all keys) on all nodes - load all keys gets called from just one node in the cluster

Comment: In hazelcast 3.3 version, Load keys are called once and I return 2 keys in it, But when I comes to loadAll, It call twice with one key as input, It performs like load() not loadAll().

For your Info,

I dont configure partition, Neither above 1000 keys, Just have two keys.

Where Am I going wrong???

Thanks and Regards, Harry

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. What you tell is correct. I'll give you some better numbers. Imagine 27100 keys in db, then loadAllKeys will load 27100 keys in 1 go. And then each partition loads 100 keys (27100/271) using the loadKeys method. In you case you only have 2 keys, so probably each key ends up at a different partition where each partition does a loadKeys with a single key. Does this make sense to you? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Small correct: each partition will load the records using the loadAll method.